# How to run ansible script from terraform

Tags: ansible, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Hi below is my requirement.
Using terraform script i create a linux vm and post that using ansible play book i install some softwares. so i have this scripts separately with me and it is working fine.

What i want to do is that as soon as the terraform script creates the vm i want to invoke ansible script from the terraform script and install the softwares from ansible script.

I tried the below code but it did not work

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = ["sudo dnf -y install python"]

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "fedora"
      private_key = "${file(var.ssh_key_private)}"
    }
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ansible-playbook -u fedora -i '${self.public_ip},' --private-key ${var.ssh_key_private} provision.yml" 
  }
```

So here i am not sure how the ansible get installed in the vm currently i am doing it manually and how thisansible script will get invoked from terraform

Error: Unknown root level key: provisioner

Comment: "it did not work" - is not specific. Why exactly it did not work? Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin Sorry forgot to mention the error : Error: Unknown root level key: provisioner

Comment: I noticed that you have lots of questions with answers, yet not a single answer was ever accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good good practice, but also helps others and eliminate duplicates. Also ppl may just skip your questions if they know there is no chance you ever accept good answer.

Comment: @Marcin I guess i mark it accepted when it works for me

Answer (score 0):

[provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/syntax.html#how-to-use-provisioners) can only be used within a `resource`, e.g.:

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  # ...

provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = ["sudo dnf -y install python"]

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "fedora"
      private_key = "${file(var.ssh_key_private)}"
    }
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ansible-playbook -u fedora -i '${self.public_ip},' --private-key ${var.ssh_key_private} provision.yml" 
  }
}
```

Comment: How do we install ansible in linux VM

Comment: @ashish It depends on which linux? You have to decide which linux to use, and find instructions for the given distro.

Comment: i am using RHEL 8 but i am not sure how to install ansible in that linux vm because the requirement is to run ansible script as soon as the linux vm is created

Comment: or is it enough to make the ansible script run if we install phyton?

Comment: @ashish I think you should make dedicate question about RHEL8 and installing ansible, as this is entirly different issue then the one you posted in the question.